# google places api - not loading properly in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use Google Places API in a Chrome extension.

I'm loading the Places script (via script tag) successfully and at that point, I can see that `window.google.maps.places` is defined.

Shortly after the script is evaluated, it appears to load the following script: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/35/7/places_impl.js`

As soon as that occurs, I get the following error in the console:

[image]

That script appears to attempt to access `window.google.maps` again, but suddenly it doesn't exist.

Here's the `permissions` section from my `manifest.json`:

```
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "identity",
        "storage",
        "https://*.googleapis.com/*"
    ],
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not all scripts can run inside an extension successfully so try debugging: set breakpoints in a normal web page and see what happens, then do the same in your extension and compare. BTW Loading remote scripts into the privileged context of extensions is a very bad idea - see if you do it inside a sandboxed iframe (via the `allow` attribute).

Comment: Thanks. These are pretty common things that I've already tried.